# Programmatically add QgsAction to Attributes form using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, widget, actions

**Context**

I am developing a QGIS plugin using QGIS 3.22.11-Białowieża. One of the functions is to add a layer to the map and format the fields in the attributes form. I want to avoid developing a custom form and just use the "drag and drop designer" layout:

```py
editFormConfig = feature_layer.editFormConfig()
editFormConfig.setLayout(1)
```

This is working great so far. I am able to customize my fields as needed and add them to the  Attributes Form just fine, for example:

```py
fields = feature_layer.fields()
field_index = fields.indexFromName(field_name)
widget_setup = QgsEditorWidgetSetup('TextEdit', {'IsMultiline': True, 'UseHtml': False})
feature_layer.setEditorWidgetSetup(field_index, widget_setup)
form_config = feature_layer.editFormConfig()
form_config.setLabelOnTop(field_index, True)
feature_layer.setEditFormConfig(form_config)
```

**The Problem**

I have a `QgsAction` (button to open URL) that I would like to add to the Attributes Form.

```py
helpAction = QgsAction(1, 'Open Help URL', help_action_text, None, capture=False, shortTitle='Help', actionScopes={'Layer'})
feature_layer.actions().addAction(helpAction)
```

This part is also working fine, the Action is added to the layer properly and is available as a widget in the drag-and-drop designer for the Attributes Form. When I manually drag the Action into the Form Layout, it appears as a button and works as expected.

However, I cannot find where to add this to the programmatically to the Attributes Form as I do with the fields. Is this even possible?

**Question**

How can I add a layer Action (`QgsAction`) to that layer's Attributes Form programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I missed this in the documentation: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.22/core/QgsAttributeEditorAction.html

```
editorAction = QgsAttributeEditorAction(helpAction, rootContainer)
rootContainer.addChildElement(editorAction)
```

Works great!

Comment: Can you give further details on the rootContainer please?

Comment: `rootContainer = editFormConfig.invisibleRootContainer()` 
see the documentation [here](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsEditFormConfig.html#qgis.core.QgsEditFormConfig.invisibleRootContainer)